# Migrate spring-boot 1.2.2 to spring-boot 2.0.3

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, migration

I am new to spring-boot and I am stuck with this issue. I am migrating a multi-module project from `spring-boot 1.2.2` to `spring-boot 2.0.3`. before jumping to `spring-boot 2.0.3` I have tried to migrate to `spring-boot 1.5.4`. But I am stuck with the same error in both cases.
I have three modules inside a parent pom.

- 1.clientModule
- 2.commonModule
- 3.serviceModule

Error is due to import of `commonModule` in `clientModule`. it says `package XXX(from commonModule)` is not exist.(This error is coming from `clientModule`) but the same code is running perfectly with `spring-boot 1.2.2`.

Comment: can you show the pom.xml ? Or whatever dependeny tool you work with

Comment: Sorry, Malik,
I am working on a confidential project. I am not allowed to expose any code.
I know it is very hard to find issue without a code. but I can ping you a very similar question I have came across on StackOverflow .
link to the question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60774767/why-am-i-obtaining-this-error-building-a-spring-boot-project-after-updating-the